# Не могу построить диаграмму

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть код, который нормально работает. Но когда я выставляю приоритет WHERE pollid =3;  Диаграмма не отображается. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку, или найти метод, как вывести данные для диаграммы с определенным значением ячейки pollid.

```html
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mysitekatya");  
 $query = "SELECT choice, count(*) as number FROM choices GROUP BY choice ";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>MyGr1</title>  
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
           function drawChart()  
           {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                          ['choice', 'Number'],  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo "['".$row["choice"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     ]);  
                var options = {  
                      title: 'Вот',  
                      //is3D:true,  
                      pieHole: 0.4  
                     };  
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
                chart.draw(data, options);  
           }  
           </script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div style="width:900px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Стоит ли заниматься йогой при беременности?</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: Где текст запроса с которым не работает?

Comment: Этот код вызывается на прямую.

Comment: Ладно, я повторю - покажите текст запроса с которым ваш код __не работает__.

Comment: $query = "SELECT choice, count(*) as number FROM choices GROUP BY choice  WHERE  pollid = 3";

Comment: А теперь откройте любое руководство по mysql. В нем вам скажут, что сначала идет `WHERE` а потом `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Даже если следовать Вашим словам, график не отображается.

Comment: Теперь надо научиться дебагать свой код.

Comment: А что именно не работает? Данные не выводит в форму? Не показывает график по данным? Будьте конкретны, «не работает» это понятие растяжимое.

Comment: Не выводит диаграмму с определенными данными.